# Custom camera view phonegap cordova

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I need to create a simple view with the image from the camera on the screen and a "take photo" button. The rest of the application is written in dojo mobile and is for android phones. I know i can use cordova for the camera and that i need to modify the existing camera plugin or create a new one in android because i don't want to use the native camera app. Can someone point me in a direction for finding something like this?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can start reading the tutorial given by google  [Controlling the Camera](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html).

Comment: Yes, this is the android approach. I was wondering if there is something like this done for cordova to use with the dojo code.